# How to listen to props changes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My component's code looks like that. Another component changes global `state` and I want to listen to a property in that `state` in `MyComponent`.

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

const MyComponent = ({state}) => {

  useEffect(() => console.log('state version is ' + state.version), [state.version])

  return (
    <></>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

`useEffect` does not fire in spite of props changing. Any suggestions? Pls ._.

Comment: What's the issue with what you currently have?

Comment: Make sure to verify that the parent component is correctly updating the state and causing MyComponent to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is correct for listening change to version parameter in state object.I tried to reproduce full functioning and it does work correctly.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const state = { version: 1 };

const My = () => {
  const [, updateState] = React.useState();
  const forceUpdate = React.useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    state.version += 1;
    forceUpdate(); 
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Change State</button>
      <MyComponent state={state} />
    </>
  );
};

const MyComponent = ({ state }) => {
  const prevState = useRef(state.version); 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (prevState.current !== state.version) {
      console.log("state changed");
      prevState.current = state.version; 
    }
  }, [state.version]);

  return <></>;
};

export default My;
```

Above code outputs `state changed` in console on clicking button , as an example to replicate behavior of changing state global object.

Comment: My `state` is not made by `useState`, it's a js object, which rewrites by other component, not a parent.

Comment: you can use empty state update to force rerender on mutating global plain state js object . and useRef in MyComponent to check for changes , updating my code to use the logic i said.